# Looping to open links in new tabs

Tags: automated-testing, functional, browsers, cross-browser-testing

I want to iteratively click each item in a structure of links and open each link in a new tab. I also want to get and print the title of each tab.

[image: example site footer links]

```java
    package basics;
    
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Set;
    
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    
    public class Naukri {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.naukri.com/top-skill-jobs");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            WebElement s = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class = 'footer anchorList']//*[@class='wrap']"));
            System.out.println(s.findElements(By.tagName("a")).size());

            // Attempt to open each link in a new tab
            for (int i=0;i<s.findElements(By.tagName("a")).size(); i++) {
                String clickonlinkTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ENTER);
                s.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(i).sendKeys(clickonlinkTab);
                Thread.sleep(3000L);
            }
    
            // Attempt to print all the open tab names.
            Set<String> ListofLinks = driver.getWindowHandles();
            Iterator<String> it = ListofLinks.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                driver.switchTo().window(it.next());
                System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    
            } 
            driver.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please explain more on this?

Comment: I want to open all 69 links in new tabs and going forward want to print all those 69 links title links on my console

Comment: Explain more on issue side also. It helps others to understand where it went wrong.

Comment: @AshutoshSingh. That's quite overkill. It's like using cannon to kill a fly -- the whole process will be pretty slow and resource consuming. Why do you use Selenium for that?

Comment: I want to open all the listed after executing the below code from script
System.out.println(s.findElements(By.tagName("a")).size());

the output of the above code is 69 while in my script the program fails in to for loop that is the program is able to go further which is causing error.

Comment: @dzieciou: I am learning selenium that is why for learning purpose I want to understand.

Comment: Simple Click() is working. If you are trying Keys.Chord .. write a different query ..

Comment: Suggestion: Be Clear with question, Clearly explain what you are trying to do. what you tried and where you got struck. also provide required samples/examples/URLs